# $\ln\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}$ - Turning it to a power series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series

Okay, I tried using $ln\left(1+x\right)$ and $ln\left(1-x\right)$ expansion, I reached:
$\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{\:1-x}\right)$
And my series right now is:
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\left[1-\left(-1\right)^n\right]x^n=\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)$$
The question, how do I apply the sqrt? I guess I cant just do sqrt to series...
How do I continue? Thanks.

EDIT: Is the answer:
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)\left[1-\left(-1\right)^n\right]x^n=ln\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}$$
I understood from comments.

Comment: $\ln \sqrt x=\frac1 2 \ln x$.

Comment: I don't understand this question but $\ln \sqrt x=\frac12\ln x$

Comment: ohh I understand.. I will edit my post, Please tell me if its good ( in a few minutes )

Comment: $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)\left[1-\left(-1\right)^n\right]x^n=ln\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}$$Is that the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\log (\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}})=\frac{1}{2}(\log (1+x)-\log (1-x))=\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n})=\\\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+(-1)^{n+1})\frac{x^n}{n}=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+O(x^7)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
for $\vert x\vert<1$

**EDIT**
It's interesting to verifie that if $f'(x)=\log(\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}})$ then $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$, and also if we express $f$ as $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ then $f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x^2)^n=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ by the geometric sum formula

Comment: Hi, so my answer is correct right? we got the same answer. and thanks for the explanation!!

Comment: Yes, your are right. Note that since all the even terms are zero we can simplifie more our expression

Comment: Oh its very good, the power series you just edited seems similliar to something I think.. Thanks!!